# Control buzzer with GPIO

Tags: microcontroller, buzzer

***Edit: Realised Silly mistake, I have the emitter and collector swapped on my PCB :( sorry about that.***

---

I'm trying to control a magnetic buzzer indicator using an STM32 MCU. I have the circuit below which although works the buzzer is extremely quiet. I have testes with a voltage meter that the transistor is switching and I a getting 3.3v across the buzzer when switched on.

Through some trial and error I found that if I short R32 the buzzer switches on correctly and is as loud as just connected directly to 3.3v and GND.

Could someone advise what is happening here? Because with R32 present I am seeing 3.3v but why is the buzzer so quiet?

[image]

The buzzer is internally driven so it just needs 3.3v across it to sound.

Comment: If you disconnect **BUZZ** input at R32 from microcontroller, and connect to +3.3V, do you get satisfactory sound? If so, then perhaps microcontroller drives **BUZZ** with PWM instead of logic high. If not, then Q1 faulty or connected backwards or otherwise improperly...or R31 is higher than 22 ohms.

Comment: If you short R32 then the transistor might burn out. R32 is needed to limit the base current of the transistor.

Comment: @glen_geek you were correct thanks I have it connected backwards. Did not think I had but checked and I got it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet of the [CMI-1295IC-0385T](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/670/cmi_1295ic_0385t-1776836.pdf) *MAGNETIC BUZZER INDICATOR* has the following *Performance Curve*:

[image]

From the above graph the resistance of the buzzer is ~170 Ohms.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFKwEC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So, with the following where `R2` simulates the nominal resistance of the buzzer, it shows that when switched by a transistor and having an additional 22 Ohm series resistor there is 2.8 V across the buzzer when switched on.

From looking at the performance curve a reduction of the voltage across the buzzer for 3.3 V to 2.8 V reduces the SPL from ~84 dB to ~82 dB. According to  [Sound level and auditory perception](https://www.acousti-tech.com/en/blog/detail/sound-level-and-auditory-perception-4129) :

> Increasing sound level : 1 to 2 dB
>
> Changing in auditory perception : Not perceptible

Therefore, the above analysis doesn't explain why switching with the transistor causes the buzzer to be *extremely quiet*.

Is the `BUZZ` output from the  STM32 MCU using PWM?

The CUI DEVICES [Buzzer Basics - Technologies, Tones, and Drive Circuits](https://www.cuidevices.com/blog/buzzer-basics-technologies-tones-and-driving-circuits) contains the following in the *Application Circuit for Magnetic or Piezo Indicator* section:

> An indicator requires only a dc voltage to operate and sound is produced whenever the voltage is present.

Therefore, with the CMI-1295IC-0385T having a built-in driving circuit, and so the STM32 MCU `BUZZ` shouldn't be using PWM.